# except KeyError as err:

Tags: python, return, key, self, except

Running the following code:

```
import re   # Biblioteca que trabalha com regular expressions

#Fefininindo areas de  categorias
areas = [ 
    'Adriana','Aldenir','Bianca','Caroline','Douglas','Jamila','Jussara','Jéssika','Luiza','Lívia','Mônica', 'Nataly', 'Pedro', 'Pharos Editora', 'Priscila', 'Robson','Sandra','Simone','Tainã','Vilma', 'Vânia'
]

def get_responsavel(responsavel:str, areas:list) -> str:
  """Extract product area from responsavel"""
  for area in areas:
    if re.match(pattern=area, string=responsavel):
      return area
  return responsavel

get_responsavel ('Aldenir', areas)
```

The above code returns 'Aldenir', ok!!!

```
# complete
df['responsavel__'] = df['responsavel_'].apply(lambda x: responsavel(x, areas))

df[['responsavel', 'responsavel_', 'responsavel__']].tail(20)
```

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3801             try:
-> 3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:


pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'responsavel_'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:
-> 3804                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3805             except TypeError:
   3806                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 'responsavel_'
```

I am DS student. This is an exercise of one of the classes. I don´t know what to do to solve the problem.